# Bootstrap Remote Content Form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a form inside a bootstrap modal. My code worked fine until I attempted to load the form into the modal remotely. Here is my code without remote loading https://jsfiddle.net/shammock112/w0jzp6sp/#

Please help.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My Modal </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="myform" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="firstname1">First name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup1" value="Sign up">Submit</button></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem probably lays within your js which you didn't post. Please show us the js code you use in the 'remote loading' case. FYI... You can place HTML, CSS, JS fiddles right here on stackoverflow with one of the buttons on top of the text area where you enter your question. No need for js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
$.get("my_modal.htm", function(data) {
$('#mymodal').find('.modal-content').html(data);
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "<i>Please enter name.</i>",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
    }
  }
});
$('#button').click(function() {
  if ($('#myform').valid()) {
    alert('form is valid');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('form is not valid');
  }
});
});
})
```

Comment: This is what I came up with but could not get Fiddle to load the remote file.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, quickly looking over it. Are there any console messages? (And if I recall correctly, validate has a debug mode!?)

Comment: Thanks, this code is fine. I just wanted to share my solution since I was having a hard time finding it.